# How to overload the << operator

Tags: c++, printing, overloading

I am trying to overload the << operator by using the code

```
inline ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Node& n){n.print(out); return out;}
```

and the print function I call is just

```
void Node::print(ostream& out){
    out<< freq << "  " << input<<"  " << Left<< "  " << Right<< endl;
}
```

Left and right are both pointers that print out in hex when I just call the print function. But when I use the << operator it just prints everything in hex i.e  0x600084d40. I don't want it printing out in Hex I want the values of freq and input when and the two hex pointers when I print it.

When I try to print it out I am printing a Node* i dont know if that has anything to do with it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: FYI, the `Node` should be passed by **constant** reference, e.g. `const Node& n`.  Also, change `Node::print` to be a constant method: `void Node::print(ostream& out) const`

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try to print it out I am printing a Node* i dont know if that has anything to do with it.

It definitely does.

```
Node* n = ...;
std::cout << n;
```

invokes overload that just prints a pointer. You need to use:

```
Node* n = ...;
std::cout << *n;
```

If you want

```
std::cout << n;
```

to work similar to

```
std::cout << *n;
```

you'll have to provide an overload.

```
inline ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Node* n)
{
   return (out << *n);
}
```

**Suggested Improvements**

`operator<<` functions should use `const&`, not a non-const reference.

```
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Node const& n);
```

That would necessitate changing `print` to a `const`-member function.

I would also recommend changing the return type of `print` to `std::ostream&`.

```
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out) const;
```

Now, the implementations would look like:

```
std::ostream& Node::print(std::ostream& out)
{
    return (out<< freq << "  " << input<<"  " << Left<< "  " << Right<< std::endl);
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Node const& n)
{
   return n.print(out);
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Node const* n)
{
   return (out << *n);
}
```

Comment: Just note: If you overload `operator<<(ostream& out, Node const* n)`, you will not be able to print the actual value of pointer to Node like this: `Node* n_ptr = new Node(); std::cout << n_ptr << std::endl`, because it will always  call the overloaded `operator<<`. In such case, you would have to avoid the overloaded operator by a trick similar to this: `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(n_ptr) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Why use the print function? Instead you could just use overloading with friend functions. Previously when implementing this I needed to pass the object by const reference like this `const Node &name`and also return an `ostream&`

Assuming that freq and input are members of the class, your code should look like this in your .cpp:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,  const Node& n)
{
   return out<<n.freq<< "  " <<n.input<<"  "<<n.Left<<"  "<< n.Right;
}
```

and this in the .h:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Node& n);
```

If this needs to take pointers you can simply modify it to be:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,  const Node* n)
{
   return out<<n->freq<< "  " <<n->input<<"  "<<n->Left<<"  "<< n->Right;
}
```

and:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Node* n);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note: The `const Node& n` overload is the golden standard, but I would probably avoid the `const Node* n` overload, because it will prevent you to be able to print the pointer value itself in scenario such as this: `Node* n = new Node(); std::cout << n << std::endl;`, which might be quite a surprise for someone who works with your code for the first time. For this, I would probably stick only to the `const Node& n` overload.

Comment: I see, so you suggest just keeping the first, and when wanting to print a pointers data i would use `<<*n` instead?

Comment: Exactly, that's IMHO the best way to go.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's approach with the `print` function.